# NiFi how do I get JSON array of string converted to comma separated plain text value and substring(1024)

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

Been at this for 5 hours trying to convert a JSON array of string values to a plain string comma separated value and trim the length via substring.

Can NiFi do this?

e.g.
Starting with

```
[
    "Charlie was here",
    "Linus was here",
    "Snoopy was here",
    "Sally was here"
]
```

I am trying to convert it to

```
Charlie was here,Linus was here,Snoopy was here,Sally was here
```

So if the above value gets stored into an attribute called 'myData'

then I can substring it to shorten the overall length and it does not matter what gets chopped off at the end.
e.g.
`myData:substring(0,1024)`

I have been trying to use the following processors, various combinations but have not been able to find the correct one to use.

- UpdateAttribute
- EvaluateJSONPath
- SplitJSON
- MergeContent

The closest I got is with the splitjson and mergecontent but then the content contains no comma separating the values and I end up with

```
Charlie was hereLinus was hereSnoopy was hereSally was here
```

Just about everything I have found posted in here deals with text convert to json but not json convert to text.

What processor am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be using ***JoltTransformJSON*** processor with the following specification :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&1[]"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=join(',',@(1,&))"// concatenate all string components separated  by comma
    }
  },
  {// derive the unnested string only 
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": ""
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]

Comment: Thank you for posting this solution as well as the screen capture. I've not seen that site before and would not have known what to do with it initially. Note: the link does not load up what is in the screen capture.

Comment: @edjm Thank you too. Unfortunately we cannot store our works unlike to some fiddles which are used for DBMS products.

Comment: Perhaps you can answer my other post on 'NiFi how do I pass an attribute to the executeScript processor' :)

Comment: @edjm yes, I'd like to but I'm experienced only on a few processes :)

Comment: Is there anyway to measure performance when performing the solution you provided to an expression language solution where I just strip out the characters? Both ways work just wondering on which is best being that I'm dealing with 100k+ records at a time.

Comment: @edjm sorry, I don't know.